# Convert all fields to uppercase with Linq

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, linq

I am using linq to query data.
But I want it return uppercase field.
Below is my code, how to transfer all field to uppercase?

```
public List<dynamic> QueryToList(string connStr, string sql)
{
 using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connStr))
 {
    conn.Open();
    var results= conn.Query(sql).ToList();
    conn.Close();
    return results; //For now, it would return all fields into lower case.
 }
}
```

**Edit:**
Thanks for @Alen.Toma, I use the code below and it return the result I want.

```
public List <dynamic> QueryToList(string connStr, string sql) 
{
conn.Open();
var results = conn.Query(sql);
conn.Close();

var valueResult = new List<dynamic>();
foreach (dynamic item in results)
{
    var dicItem = item as IDictionary<string, object>;
    var x = new ExpandoObject();
    foreach (var i in dicItem.Keys)
    {
        ((ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>)x).Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>(i.ToUpper(), dicItem[i]));
    }
    valueResult.Add(x);
}
return valueResult; 
}
```

Comment: Why do that? What you posted doesn't return lowercase ,it returns whatever the original data is. Converting to uppercase wastes memory for no benefit though. SQL comparisons are typically case-insensitive (depending on the column collation). You can perform case-insensitive comparisons in code. If you want to display some data in uppercase, the best place is the display form itself, eg as a format string on a Textbox or grid

Comment: In any case you aren't using LINQ, you're using Dapper. The easiest way to convert strings to uppercase is the SQL query.

Comment: Since I am using postgreSQL, so the field will return lower case, but I want its field return upper case without changing SQL. Thanks for your devices!

Comment: No it won't - no database is going to modify the data by itself. You still haven't explained why you want to return uppercase. What's the *real* problem you assume will be solved if you return uppercase? Most likely, that conversion isn't needed

Comment: Unless you mean you want to change the *field names*? Just use column aliases in the query. `SELECT myfield as MyField, ....`

Comment: Yes, I mean change the field names, since there are too many SQL so I can't modify all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Well I agree with @Panagiotis Kanavos, even better is to convert the data to an class object.

Incase you still want to do it as such

Here is an example.

```js
public List <dynamic> QueryToList(string connStr, string sql) {
  var valueResult = new List <dynamic> ();
  using(OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connStr)) {
    conn.Open();
    var results = conn.Query(sql).ToList();
    conn.Close();
    foreach(var item in results) {
      var dicItem = item as Dictionary <string,object> ;
      var x = new ExpandoObject();
      forEach(var i in dicItem.Keys)
        ((ICollection<KeyValuePair <string, object>>)x).Add(i.ToUpper(), dicItem[i]);
      valueResult.Add(x);
    }

    return valueResult;
  }
}
```

Comment: I edit a little and it works now, thanks!

Comment: Np, I wrote it on the fly without testing so there is no way it could have worked without a little bug :) Anyway since all that worked for you can you please mark this as answered